# ZTE (Airtel 4G) 4g dongle connection issue, connected to dongle but ping fails

Tags: pi-3, usb, internet

I am trying to connect Airtel 4G dongle (ZTE) to RP 3, I used wvdial. I am able to connect to dongle but couldn't ping. Ping gives "host unreachables" message. Attaching the routing table, wvdial config info and ifconfig info.

Could you guys please check and help to resolve this issue.

[image: ifconfig,netstat]

[image: wvdial,wvdial.conf]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding, ppp0 as default gateway.

Command: sudo route add default dev ppp0